# How to read SVCLOG files in C#

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, streamreader

I need to find the tag `<ns2:Response>400 or 200 etc</n2:Response>` using service trace viewer it look something like this!!

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-14799">
    <ns2:SendInvoice xmlns:ns2="http://www.zadrwan.com/services/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.zadrwan.com/services/DocumentSendTo" xmlns:ns4="http://www.zadrwan.com/services/VersionRequest">                            
    <ns2:Response>200</ns2:Response>
    <ns2:Comments>Success!.</ns2:Comments>
    </ns2:SendInvoice>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Or is there another way to get a variable without using an XML reader (to read all the document) or, in this case, a text reader (I'm redesigning a VB project that used a `StreamReader`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways.  Since there is a schema and you can use the xsd.exe tool to get classes I would use code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TimestampType));
            TimestampType timeStamp = (TimestampType)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated by a tool.
    //     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.6421
    //
    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    //     the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // 
    // This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
    // 


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xs" +
        "d")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Timestamp", Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xs" +
        "d", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class TimestampType {

        private AttributedDateTime createdField;

        private AttributedDateTime expiresField;

        private System.Xml.XmlElement[] itemsField;

        private string idField;

        private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public AttributedDateTime Created {
            get {
                return this.createdField;
            }
            set {
                this.createdField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public AttributedDateTime Expires {
            get {
                return this.expiresField;
            }
            set {
                this.expiresField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Items {
            get {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, DataType="ID")]
        public string Id {
            get {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
            get {
                return this.anyAttrField;
            }
            set {
                this.anyAttrField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xs" +
        "d")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Expires", Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xs" +
        "d", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class AttributedDateTime {

        private string idField;

        private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, DataType="ID")]
        public string Id {
            get {
                return this.idField;
            }
            set {
                this.idField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
        public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
            get {
                return this.anyAttrField;
            }
            set {
                this.anyAttrField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
        public string Value {
            get {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }


}
```